# Migrating springboot 3 app to graalVM and providing properties at runtime

Tags: spring-boot, graalvm, graalvm-native-image, spring-boot-3

I really want to migrate my app to native image.
Currently it's just a jar. I struggle with many dynamic features like @Value.
I also use placeholders in application.properties e.g. picture.size=${SIZE} then it's fetched from my environment variables.

Normally it works, just not with graalVM compatible jdk. That's why I cannot build app with graalVM compatible jdk because I get errors like

```
Could not resolve placeholder...
```

Is there a way to provide environment variables at runtime for native image. Do these placeholder needs to be filled up at buildtime or is it possible to fill them up at native image runtime. What about properties which are fetched from env variables in a way I described?